# Cannot SPOOL long header in a file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, spool

I am trying to spool a header with 208 fields in a file

```
  set feedback off
  set verify off
  set head off
  set echo off
  set pages 0
  set trimspool on
  SET LINESIZE 500

spool ${FILE_NAME}

select 'Field1,Field2,.........Field208'
from dual;

 SPOOL OFF
 exit
```

I'm getting the following error

```
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
```

How do I achieve the task ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your string literal into two or more lines, to avoid [the SQL*Plus command line limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apa.htm#SQPUG141) (which is nothing to do with spooling). You can then concatenate the separate string literals together to get the output on a single line:

```
select 'Field1,Field2,.........Field99'
    || 'Field101,Field102,.........Field199'
    || 'Field201,Field202,.........Field208'
from dual;
```

How may times you need to split the string, and where, depends on your actual values.

You will also need to set your `linesize` much higher than the 500 you currently have, or it will wrap the output onto several lines anyway; it needs to be at least 2500 since you're already reaching at least that, but probably quite a bit more - again depending on your actual data. Maybe you meant 5000...

Answer (score 0):

> SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

You have hit a limitation of **SQL*Plus**, which has an absolute limit on the length of line of **2,499 characters**.

The only way to do it in SQL*Plus is to have **line breaks** in your SQL statement instead of a single line and concatenate each line with the previous one.

For example,

**Change this:**

```
SQL> SELECT 'lalitkumar' NAME from dual;

NAME
----------
lalitkumar
```

**To this:**

```
SQL> select 'lalit'
  2  ||'kumar' name from dual;

NAME
----------
lalitkumar

SQL>
```

Comment: Just putting a line break in the select list would split the output into two lines, which wouldn't be useful as say the head line in a CSV file (which this seems to be). And embedding CHR(13) just exceeds the limit even further?

Comment: I meant to concatenate it after each line break, someone my hands didn't type what was in the head ;-)

Comment: But you still don't want line breaks in the *output*, surely? That's changing the OP's result?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, since it is header, no need of `chr(10)` as it would split the line. I missed that part. It just need to change the way data is posted to the client SQL*Plus and not the output.